# method to determine if age square is == to current year

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method that determines if the square of the age of a person is equal to the current year. For example a man was aged 43 in 1849 and the square of 43 is 1849. Below is my code for it but I dont know why my exception is not working because it is assumed that no body can live past 123 years

```
 public class Augustus 
 {
    private int year;
    private final static  int RANGEOFLIVING=124;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       Augustus y = new Augustus(1806); 
       System.out.println(y.isAlive());
    }

    public Augustus(int n)
    {
        year= n;
    }

    public int SquareOfAge(int z)
    {
       return z * z ;
    }

   public boolean isAlive()
   {
       for(int i=1;i<RANGEOFLIVING;i++)
         if (SquareOfAge(i)!=year++)
               return false;
          return true;


   }
}
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?  Also, is this homework?

Comment: Why didn't you edit your previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577135/application-to-determine-if-living-age-is-square-of-year) ? and again, is this homework ?

Comment: Some random comments: It looks like you just want to see what age squared, is equal to some year. Wouldn't it be better to just take the square root of the year, and return true if it's a whole number, less than 124. Also curious why you made SquareOfAge a public method. Seems like this is a helper method, which doesn't need to be public.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to return false out of the loop. This will abort at the first iteration. You want to continue running the loop until you have found an age/year combination that matches, and then return true.

Comment: Yep, and then return false at the end if the loop ended without a match.

Comment: @ thilo i have tried it but am still getting the wrong answer can you please explain furthur what you mean

Comment: I am also a bit suspicious if the year++ works correctly, or if you are maybe one year off. Add some debugging output to see if the age/year combinations that are being evaluated match your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the test the see if they are alive and if the current year is the square of an age.
For example:

```
private boolean isAlive(int age){
  return age < RANGEOFLIVING;
}

private boolean isSquare(int age){
  return isAlive(age) && year == age*age;
}
```

Unless that is not what you're after? That's just what I gathered from reading the description of your question. Not sure why you need the loop at all?
But I may be misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Java in a while, so forgive me if I sound stupid.

It looks like you're using SquareOfAge() as a static method, and therefore it should either have a static declaration, like this:

```
public static int SquareOfAge(int z)
{
   return z * z ;
}
```

or be used as `this.SquareOfAge(i)`. However, this is also bad programming because you're calling `this` for no reason. This looks like homework so I'll stop here.